# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant PollsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, circular-dependency, rapidfire-gem

I am trying to build a custom polling functionality by inheriting Rapidfire with my controllers.

```
class PollsController < Rapidfire::PollsController
```

The line above shows an error, while the same thing runs successfully in another controller:

```
class QuestionsController < Rapidfire::QuestionsController
```

I followed the same procedure and also extended the controller with Rapidfire.

[image: error screen]

Comment: What version of rapidfire are you using? I'm looking in the [rapidfire docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/search/gems/rapidfire/2.1.0?q=PollsController) and don't see a PollsController class.

Comment: I am in agreement with @maxpleaner. Reviewing the tagged releases on GitHub shows nothing of a `PollsController` in any of the versions. Are you sure you didn't mean `RapidFire::SurveysController` or `RapidFire::ApplicationController`?

Comment: Actually PollsController is the controller in which we want to extend the functionality of rapidfire and the version i am using is 3.0.